# How to put input and dropdown side by side in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

New to bootstrap and been struggling with this implementation.
I want to have a text input and drop down toggle with no margin's but I can't seem to figure it out.

This is what I'd like it to be like:
[image]

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="60" disabled>
  </div>
  <div class="col"><button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle btn-square-only" disabled>months</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what I am getting. The btn-square-only just is a styling feature nothign else. Any ideas?
[image]

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: No need to both `input` and `button` element in two columns so you can follow `bootstrap doc`: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/input-group/#buttons-with-dropdowns

Comment: @RaeeshAlam Oh that's perfect, I am not sure how I missed this! Can't seem to get the spacing right though.

Comment: `@Safder` Is you want gap between input and button?

Comment: @RaeeshAlam No I want the input to be small to fill just 60 and months be just enough to fill months. As in my example.

Comment: Okay its so simple just wrap with `parent div` and define width as you want.

Comment: Let me add example for as your image view input+dropdown button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow below `Bootstrap` structure and define width as you want so I have define `width-150px` class with has `150px width` of **input-group** div.

```css
.width-150px{
  width: 150px!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container my-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="input-group width-150px">
        <input type="text" class="form-control text-center rounded-0" placeholder="60" disabled>
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle rounded-0" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" disabled>Month</button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">January</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">February</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">March</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This exactly what I was looking for, wasn't sure where the width went. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

group`. You can find more [via bootstrap official documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/forms/)

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
 <div class="form-group row ">
        <div class="col-3 pr-0">
            <input type="text" class="form-control mx-0 " placeholder="60" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 px-0"><button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle btn-square-only mx-0 "
                disabled>months</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Also if you inspect the elements with computed tab you see that how margin and padding affect to the `<div>` .That is why I have put `pr-0` and `mx-0`.
Thanks

Comment: This works as well, any idea how to make the input side smaller as my example picture?

Comment: Editing the padding and margin, independently resize the input and button but not together. Would you be able to recreate my example with your code?

Comment: @Safder If you want smaller input & button then need to add `form-group-sm` with `form-group` class.

Comment: Agreed with @RaeeshAlam s answer

Comment: Having a little bit of an issue with the sizing but it is the overall answer. Thank you.